# Signing meesage | hex string has length 64, want 40 for common.Address

Tags: web3js, signature

I am using 'web3.eth.sign` to sign a message, using following code snippet:

```
web3.eth.sign(msgHash, address, async (err, signedMsg) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
    resolve(false)
  } else {
    let { r,s,v } = await getRSV(signedMsg)
    resolve({ r,s,v })
  }
```

Where:

```
address: 0x7b9f2B209A6CeF0525e49aE1409a21F3E6f33E6B
masgHash: 0x1df7d7e71ce2983d96a3579b72721945407e0b6887dfb20cc5d9dac03352e765
```

But this giver error

> Node error: {"code":-32602,"message":"invalid argument 0: hex string
>   has length 64, want 40 for common.Address"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on web3.js v0.x, where the order of the first two arguments to this function is opposite to that of web3.js v1.x:

- Web3.js v0.x: [`web3.eth.sign(address, dataToSign, [, callback])`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign)
- Web3.js v1.x: [`web3.eth.sign(dataToSign, address [, callback])`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign)

Comment: Thanks. I am using `web3@1.0.0-beta.48`, so I was doing it right. I can verify that as when I switch the params, I get error: ` Error: Provided address "0x1df7d7e71ce2983d96a3579b72721945407e0b6887dfb20cc5d9dac03352e765" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed`

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh: You might want to try v37 or lower. I'm pretty sure that there are various problems in later versions (I'm personally staying at 34 for now).

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. Will switch to 34 :)

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh: With regards to your actual problem - have you made sure to use strings (and not numbers, since those would be too large for JS)?

Comment: Yes values are strings. I can confirm that

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh: BTW, is the error emitted in the `if` or thrown in the `else`?

Comment: It was from  inside the err function.

Comment: Downgrading to v 34 resolved the issue. Thanks :)